# How to run code on Android Studio with an Android API lower than 20?

Tags: android, api, android-studio, debugging

I'm writing the code for an app on Android Studio and when I try to run or debug the code, I'm not allowed and a message pops up saying "Instant run is not supported on devices with API levels 20 or lower". I'm using a Samsung Note 5 so it's not too old and I really don't know much about API levels. What should I do to run the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Instant Run:
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run and uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.
Please refer this link for more information: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use android studio emulator or genymotion emulator to setup API level more than 20

here is a list of Android API levels
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

Answer (score 0):

just use emulator that bellow 20.
you can use default android studio emulator, or genymotion or any android emulator.
and 1 more thing is when you run ur apps dont use instant run.
but first you have to set ur api bellow 20 too.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to connect your Android-device to the PC and have activated the Debugging mode. Don't deactivate the screen of your smartphone, but let it be activated and accessible.
If you had recently an error in your Android-Studio, then invalidate the cache and restart android studio. If you restart Android-Studio, wait at the beginning for Android-Studio to be done with all its processes in the background. After having started Android-Studio, go to the terminal and enter the following lines.

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

Then start server with

```
sudo adb start-server
```

It's essential, that you use "sudo". When starting server, then you'll get a question on your smartphone concerning the connection attempt. Check the checkbox and accept the connection. If you don't use the "sudo" keyword, then you'll get that error message.

If you've done everything properly, then you can click on the debug-sign and select your device as shown in the popup-list.
This is how it worked for me.